# Possible for an Angular component to capture a keydown event when no element has focus?

Tags: angular

I have a grid like component as the only active element on my page.  The grid is built with divs set to `display: flex` and I'd like to capture various keyboard events like the arrow keys to set highlighting (using ngClass) on different cells in the grid, I'm not sure but not sure where I can capture the keydown event when none of the cells have focus.  The problem is particular to the scenario where a range of cells is set as the "select area" , but none of which have focus.
I have no problem setting the highlight on the cells I want to show as "selected", but if none have focus, I don't know where I can trap the keyboard arrow key events to select or extend the selection range.  (similar to say, the result of `shift ArrowRight` in excel.

Comment: Listen for keydown on the `window`?

Comment: HOw do I get access to the window inside the component?

Comment: If you have no focus then you can set on your first cell by default

Comment: If I can avoid it, I don’t want to set focus on the first div element because angular will puts a blue focus border  on the cell that has focus

Comment: It does not work if you set the keydown event on the enclosing tag? Like 
`<div (keydown)="..."> ... cell divs ... </div>`

Comment: @user1023110 Maybe this only works in React, but I believe you can just say `window`, it's a the global object in the browser.

Answer (score 0):

I decided to solve this by creating a dummy root element on my grid which I set the focus to when I don't want any of my grid cells to have have focus, and using css to set it so it doesn't show when its selected with this css.

```
#root-element:focus {
    outline: none;
}
```

Then I added a key down listener to this element to capture arrow key events.